# Convert cs. File to exe. File, from another console application program

Tags: c#, console-application, computer-science

I have a question.
I want my program to create a new cs. File (console application), and than to make it an exe file. 
Does it possible? How?
Thanks, 
Tom

Edit:
sorry for not being clear. I mean not to rename the file's ending. what i mean is how to make a program that will make an Execution file from a code file (such as cs. files)

Comment: do you want just to rename the file?

Comment: you should be a little more specific when explaining what you want to do.
Basically it is possible. How to do it depends strongly on whether you just want to write into a file with the ending **.cs** and rename it or whether you want to create a real C# class and compile it to a working program. so what is it?

Comment: i want to make an program, that creats an "hello world" code and saves it to an empty text file, and than makes an Execution file from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear nor specific but I´ll try to give you some basic information about compiling a C# class. 
If you are using a text file you can either use Java-compiler like *java* from **Sun** or C# compiler like *csc* from **Microsoft**. Although the ending .cs is used frequently it is not necessary in order to compile. Just make sure to have a Main() if you want to make your file executable.

```
csc myClass.cs
```

Should do the job in your cmd with the csc compiler. You can execute myClass.exe with:

```
myClass
```

You can add */out* as an option to change the name of the output file.

However, if you want to compile your class to be used by another class you have to compile it as a module:

```
csc /t:module myClass.cs
```

It will be saved as **myClass.netmodule**.

Answer (score 2):

.cs file is nothing but a plain text file, written in C# language.

You can use this MSDN reference to make a plain text file:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

As for compiling, it can be done by running `csc.exe` using proper parameter. MSDN reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx